# Server migration

Tags: cron, migration

I need to do a migration of virtual host to another virtual host transfer , Both of them are hosted on Rackspace , OS (Red hat 4 ).
client is using this server for hosting  more than 10 live sites , lots of files in /var/www. 
I transferred all files and db  from old to new , 
My questions:
what else should I need to worry about ?
how to  transfer all cron job too? 
do I need to make entry of each site on httpd.conf or rackspace will do it , during IP swapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prime Example of why everyone needs thorough server documentation.   :)

If Rackspace is handling the migration i'd ask them what they cover vs what your responicible for.

Otherwise you'll need to break down what the server does

*(and i STRONGLY suggest keeping this for future reference)*

- Applications (apache, proftp, webmin,mysql, samba, nfs, so on and so forth)
- Configuration (cronjobs, Ip settings,custom scripts,firewall settings)
- Network Communication (what servers talk to this server? how does that work?)
- Install Software Keys (if any software is installed that uses keys)

I hope you have access to your server after the new server goes "live" because as this is an undocumented server, you **WILL** miss something.

Comment: From my experience, most host providers are responsible for operating system only, so if you install Apache after the fact, then you'll most likely be migrating it now.